# GDAL Translate GeoTIFF to ASC creates a mirror image

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I created a heat map using the HeatMap plugin in QGIS from spatial points with EPSG: 4326 CSR. I want to use this layer as a bias layer for MaxEnt which only takes files in ASC format. However, Heat Map doesn't have the option for creating density maps in ASC directly so my output is in GeoTIFF. I am trying to translate the GeoTIFF to ASC format but GDAL is creating a mirrored image of my layer. The top half of the picture is the original final.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there an alternative procedure to translate my GeoTIFF? Or is there a way to fix the mirrored layer? [image]

Comment: Add gdalinfo report of the original GeoTIFF and the converted .asc file.

Comment: It looks like the GeoTIFF isn't in Upper Left orientation, it's been a while since I've seen one like that.. where did the GeoTIFF come from? Can you export in a format like IMG or BMP/BPW, both of these only support upper left orient and may help solve your problem but it is critical to see the GDALInfo reports of both datasets as @user30184 said.

Comment: Also try `gdalwarp` from tiff to asc instead of `gdal_translate`.